# Draw a line between coordinates (using svg)

Tags: jsp, svg

appreciate some help embedding what I think is an svg path element into an if statement in a jsp.

I present an icon at a set location and then, if the location changes, I re-present an icon at the new location, this works properly using two variables.

```
var xx=response[1];
var yy=response[2];
```

I want to 'draw' a line or arrow between the current location and new using the path element (svg) but am not sure how to implement svg inside an if statement in a jsp

```
if((xx != oldxx || yy != oldyy) 
{
```

I believe the statement should be something like -

```
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="L xx yy" fill="transparent" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

but do not want to reference external websites (w3.org) so presumably need to embed some or all of svg inside the jsp and call the path element inside an if statement. Apologies my coding skills are relatively weak.

Attempted the following but this results in the original icon disappearing and no drawn lines (the commented out line cause syntax issues)

```
var xx=response[1];
var yy=response[2];

if(xx != oldxx || yy != oldyy)
{
addImg(assetid, xx, yy, ' ', name, icon);
<svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<%--
<path d="M $(oldxx) $(oldyy) L $(xx) $(yy)" fill="transparent" stroke="black"/>
--%>
<path d="M oldxx oldyy L xx yy" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"/>
</svg>
}
```

Assistance appreciated.
Regards
Active

Comment: The `xmlns` value is not an actual URL, it looks like a URL, but it is actually just a string constant that signifies that this XML file is an SVG document.  Having said all that, you only need it for external SVG files (eg. `<img src="foo.svg"/>`), not ones that are inlined in the HTML page.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I am mainly stuck trying to figure out how to 'embed' the svg inside the if statement, probably something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
<c:if test="$(xx != oldxx || yy != oldyy)">
  <svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M $(oldxx) $(oldyy) L $(xx) $(yy)" fill="none" stroke="black"
          stroke-width="4"/>
  </svg>
</c:if>
```

Or if it is in the middle of a block of code, you may prefer to do:

```
if (xx != oldxx || yy != oldyy)
{ %>
  <svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M $(oldxx) $(oldyy) L $(xx) $(yy)" fill="none" stroke="black"
          stroke-width="4"/>
  </svg>
<% )
```

You'll also have to take into consideration how you position it at the right place on your page.  You haven't specified how you are drawing the rest of your page (icons etc), so I can't help with that part.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: You may also need to add some `<c:set />` elements for your coordinate variables.

Comment: Results in original icon disappearing and no drawn lines. Syntax error on token, misplaced construct relating to the final /> which is odd